# in R, how to make the wide form data structure to long form?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a wide form dataset (df).

To make it as a long form like df2,

I commanded below codes and made df1.

```
df1 <- pivot_longer(df, cols = 3:5, names_to = "year", values_to = "value")
```

I want to know how I can reshape df1 to df2.
Also, If there is another wise way to reshape the date structure more easily from df to df2, let me know please.

Thanks in advance.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"),
                 variable = c("age", "age", "education", "education"),
                 "2000" = c(1, 1), 
                 "2001" = c(1, 1),
                 "2002" = c(1, 1))

df1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"),
                 variable = c("age", "education"),
                 year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002), 
                 value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"),
                  year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002),
                  age = c(1, 1, 1),
                  education = c(1, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `recast` from `reshape2` package

```
dplyr::rename(df, var = variable) %>%
  reshape2::recast(id+variable~var)

Using id, var as id variables
  id variable age education
1  a    X2000   1         1
2  a    X2001   1         1
3  a    X2002   1         1
4  b    X2000   1         1
5  b    X2001   1         1
6  b    X2002   1         1
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   pivot_longer(3:5, names_to = 'year') %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = variable)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  id    year    age education
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a     X2000     1         1
2 a     X2001     1         1
3 a     X2002     1         1
4 b     X2000     1         1
5 b     X2001     1         1
6 b     X2002     1         1
```

---

Edit:

To convert the names to numeric you could use `names_prefix` to remove the characters then `names_transform` to convert to numeric:

```
df %>%
     pivot_longer(3:5, names_to = 'year', 
        names_prefix = "X", names_transform = as.numeric) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = variable)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  id     year   age education
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a      2000     1         1
2 a      2001     1         1
3 a      2002     1         1
4 b      2000     1         1
5 b      2001     1         1
6 b      2002     1         1
```

Comment: And you can throw in a `%>% mutate(year = as.numeric(str_replace(year, "X", "")))` after the first pivot.

Comment: ... or rather `%>% pivot_longer(-c(id, variable),  names_to = "year", names_transform=list(year = ~ sub("^\\D*", "", .x))) %>%` if OP doesn't use `check.names=F` while creating the data frame.

Comment: @AndreWildberg just use `names_prefix ="X"` should drop it.

Answer (score 0):

Using`reshape`.

```
reshape(df, varying=3:5, idvar=1:2, sep='', timevar='year', direction='long') |>
  reshape(idvar=c('id', 'year'), timevar='variable', direction='wide')
#            id year X.age X.education
# a.age.2000  a 2000     1           1
# b.age.2000  b 2000     1           1
# a.age.2001  a 2001     1           1
# b.age.2001  b 2001     1           1
# a.age.2002  a 2002     1           1
# b.age.2002  b 2002     1           1
```

Or using `melt` and `dcast` after cleaning names with `sub`.

```
reshape2::melt(setNames(df, sub('^X', '', names(df))), 1:2, 3:5, variable.name='year') |>
  reshape2::dcast(id + year ~ variable)
#   id year age education
# 1  a 2000   1         1
# 2  a 2001   1         1
# 3  a 2002   1         1
# 4  b 2000   1         1
# 5  b 2001   1         1
# 6  b 2002   1         1
```